# Azure Virtual Machine VMRole SLA

Tags: azure, azure-vm-role

I understand that Virtual Machines in Azure are still in Early Preview but am I right in thinking that is likely that once out of early preview the SLA would be the same as Web and Worker roles?

Also does anyone know when the Early Preview will finish?

Thank you
Andrew

Answer (score 1):

When GA (General Availability, or "out of Preview") the SLA for Virtual Machines is expected to be very like as the SLA for Cloud Services (Web/Worker Roles). Meaning NO SLA for single instance, but 99.95% for 2 instance setup.
No one knows yet when the Preview will be over and GA will come.

Comment: Has anyone heard any rumors of when VM will be in GA or out of Preview?